# Word matching in Python

Tags: python, django

I have this but it's doing partial matching:

```
for il in ignore_list:
    if il.word in title or il.word in text:
        return True
```

How can I only match whole words?

Comment: Give an example of what is happening, and what you want to happen. What do "text" and "title" look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to split your title and text strings into lists of words:

```
if il.word in title.split() or il.word in text.split():
```